# Ruby gem already activated

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bundler

How can I de-activate the newer version of cucumber, or get this to work with the earlier version?

```
user$ rake features
(in /Users/user/Project)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -I    "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.1/lib:lib" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-   0.6.1/bin/cucumber" --format pretty
can't activate cucumber (= 0.4.4, runtime) for [], already activated cucumber-0.6.1 for [] (Gem::LoadError)
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:280:in `activate'
```

Comment: how did this end up ? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try removing 0.6.1 entirely and seeing if it will run with just 0.4.4 installed.

If not, you need to track down what is requiring 0.4.4 and change it to >= and see if that works.

Comment: I tried that, it gives me this:

no such file to load -- cucumber/rails/world (MissingSourceFile)
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `polyglot_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.2.9/lib/polyglot.rb:70:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/Users/ericsorenson/RubyOnRails/qwantime/features/support/env.rb:4
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
...

Comment: After removing and reinstalling gems for what seemed like days, your advice was accurate. Hopefully Gem Bundler will help with this kind of thing in the future?

Answer (score 0):

There are some simple tweaks you can use so multiple versions of Cucumber play nice with each other:

http://gem-session.com/2010/04/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-cucumber-in-parallel

Answer (score 0):

A nice longer term solution is to use rvm, and gemsets.
Once you install rvm this post is very handy indeed.

http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/4